# Android Dynamic Array ListPreference

Tags: android, arrays, dynamic, listpreference

How to Create Dynamic Array For ListPreference From Java Side.

I Don't use Below Xml .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="listArray">
 <item>Value 1</item>
 <item>Value 2</item>
<item>Value 3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="listValues">
 <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
 <item>3</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474707/how-to-fill-listpreference-dynamically-when-onpreferenceclick-is-triggered

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Place preferences.xml in res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Some title">     

        <ListPreference android:key="default_category"
            android:title="Dynamic categories" android:summary="Dynamic categories summary"
            android:defaultValue="0" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

In your activity that extends PreferenceActivity you do something like this in onCreate().

```
ListPreference listPreferenceCategory = (ListPreference) findPreference("default_category");
if (listPreferenceCategory != null) {
    ArrayList<Category> categoryList = getCategories();
    CharSequence entries[] = new String[categoryList.size()];
    CharSequence entryValues[] = new String[categoryList.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Category category : categoryList) {
        entries[i] = category.getCategoryName();
        entryValues[i] = Integer.toString(i);
        i++;
    }
    listPreferenceCategory.setEntries(entries);
    listPreferenceCategory.setEntryValues(entryValues);
}
```

Comment: code is work but clicked the listpreference then error exception?

Comment: your code is changed but clicked preference then raise error.

Comment: 05-26 14:01:55.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4827): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 05-26 14:01:55.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4827):     at android.preference.ListPreference.findIndexOfValue(ListPreference.java:169)

Comment: 05-26 14:01:55.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4827):     at android.preference.ListPreference.getValueIndex(ListPreference.java:178)

Comment: I happened to see you code before it was removed.

int c = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<=ar.length-1; i++) { 
    entries[c] = ar[c]; 
    entryValues[c] = ar[c]; 
    c++;
   }