# ListPreference that contains dynamic data from MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a `ListPreference` that displays a list of successfully connected IP addresses.

I mark an IP address as successfully connected in my `MainActivity` and I was hoping there was a way that I can append the successful IP address as an array to `SharedPreferences` somehow so that when the user opens the `PreferencesActivity`, there is a `ListPreference` that shows the IP addresses I marked as a success.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034709/custom-listpreference-with-dynamic-entries) post already and it's really close but I don't think I can convert a `SharedPreference` string set to a `CharSequence[]` can I?

Here's my code so far:

```
public class IPHistoryListPreference extends ListPreference {

   SharedPreferences sharedPref;

   public IPHistoryListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   }

   public IPHistoryListPreference(Context context) {
       super(context);
       sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   }

   @Override
   protected View onCreateDialogView() {
       ListView view = new ListView(getContext());
       view.setAdapter(adapter());
   }

   private ListAdapter adapter() {
       return new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
   }

   private CharSequence[] entries() {
    //convert sharedPref stringSet to CharSequence[] ?
   }

   private CharSequence[] entryValues() {
    //convert sharedPref stringSet to CharSequence[] ?
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe your response into a string and then do a split into an array to get each IP address.

```
Eg string IPS = "some IP address|some IP address......
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a bit of a hacky solution.

First was converting a `Set<String>` to a `CharSequence[]`:

```
Set<String> stringSet = sharedPref.getStringSet("IPEntries", null);
    return stringSet.toArray(new CharSequence[stringSet.size()]);
```

Then to extract the set in my MainActivity, I just used this code:

```
Set<String> set = sharedPref.getStringSet("IPEntries", null);
if (set == null) {
                set = new HashSet<>();
                set.add(ipAddressName);
            }
            if (!set.contains(ipAddressName)) {
                set.add(ipAddressName);
            }
            sharedPref.edit().putStringSet("IPEntries", set).apply();
```