# ListPreference, get value from fragment

Tags: java, android, listpreference, getvalue

My app contains a **listPreference** with entries and an entryValues list in my strings.xml

I want to **receive the value** of the currently selected entry in a **PreferenceFragment**.

Right now, I use the following code to fetch these values, (and later on, convert the string into an integer to uuse it for an URL that depends on variables).

```
 @Nullable
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);


ListPreference lP = (ListPreference) findPreference("example_list");
String currValue = lP.getValue();

int aktuelleklasse = Integer.valueOf(currValue);


return myView;
}
```

unfortunately, I get an error, saying

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.preference.ListPreference.getValue()' on a null object reference*

So what do I need to do to get my value withouut error?
(I've got quite basic skills so dont judge me, if thats an obvious problem :))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing a `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencesFile)` before this code section?

See [PreferenceFragment.findPreference always returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339550/preferencefragment-findpreference-always-returns-null)

Comment: No, could you please tell me, where I need to look for my corresponding text for "preferencesFile"?

Comment: It's the name of your preferences XML file. See the Vogella tutorial at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html#create-preference-file

Comment: oh, I could have thought about that xD. Thanks a lot! Everything works fine now!

Comment: No problems. Awesome!